# Extract the href value (alone) for the specified class using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string with some links like below,

```
Some text will come here <a class="checkSomething" href="https://something.com" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 17px;">Check Status</a>. Some text will come here <a href="#">Click</a> Some text will come here.
```

From the above string I want extract the `href` value where class name is `checkSomething`.

Basically I have to get the link alone, that is https://something.com

I tried the below regex

```
/<a class="checkSomething" href="([^"]*)">/
```

But it gives link with `<a>` tag like below

```
<a class="checkSomething" href="https://something.com"
```

Can someone help me on this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's gotta be said again: [*don't parse HTML with a regular expression*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/257182).

Comment: Try this `/class="checkStatusNowLink" href="([^"]+)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/class="checkStatusNowLink" href="([^"]+)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQ5rI4/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably parse HTML with a regular expression, so don't. You can however use the host's built–in parser, then get the A elements and return the value of the *href* attribute for those that have it.

Not all A elements are links, some are anchors so don't have *href* attributes. In that case, *getAttribute* will return *null* which (being falsey) *filter* will not add to the returned array.

```js
var s = 'Some text will come here <a class="checkSomething" href="https://something.com" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 17px;">Check Status</a>. Some text will come here <a href="#">Click</a> Some text will come here.'

function getHREFs(markup) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = markup;
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(el.querySelectorAll('a'), function(a) {
    return a.getAttribute('href');
  })
}

document.write(getHREFs(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea you are using browser or Node.js.

## For Node.js

**Code need [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) module to work which is really recommend when process DOM with js.**

```
'use strict';
const str = 'Some text will come here <a class="checkSomething" href="https://something.com" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 17px;">Check Status</a>. Some text will come here <a href="#">Click</a> Some text will come here.';
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const $ = cheerio.load(str);
$('a.checkSomething').each(function() {
  console.info($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Link to this: https://tonicdev.com/56d349553836000d00e1452f/57044ede2d5c971100488733

## For Browser

Someone already did.